# How to fix java 38 error cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Hi guys can you help me fix this error I am not sure what to do and I have been trying to resolve it for a long time, stackoverflow is not allowing me to post because my post is more code than is description but this is the error I am getting please help

```
/PROG3.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    static int size = Taskdetails.getNumberOfTasks();
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getNumberOfTasks()
  location: variable Taskdetails of type String
1 error
```

I will appreciate your inputs

Comment: Most likely you are facing one of problems described at: [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706216)

Comment: It says `Taskdetails` is a variable of type `String`, and `String` does not have a `getNumberOfTasks()` method. The exact fix is impossible to guess without a [mre].

Comment: Based on `location: variable Taskdetails of type String` need to agree with @Slaw. This is good example why *variables* should start with `lowerCase` and *types* `UpperCase` so we could easier recognize or even prevent those kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You named a variable `Taskdetails` of type String. And in the line in the error message, you try to access its method `getNumberOfTasks` which is not present in the String class.